# php из xml в mysql

Tags: php, mysql, xml

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]есть такой xml

```
<goods>
<good sh="123" name="qwe" ed="oopopop" cost="123456"/>
<good sh="001" name="asdf" ed="zxcczxc" cost="56742"/>
</goods>
```

мне нужно данные этого xml засунуть в mysql
pastebin.com/24YuiuCq - последний код , в чем ошибка?
написал скрипт на php, но он не робит, в чем проблема?

на картинке скрыл некоторые переменные переменные)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещен в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40310/discussion-on-question-by-martinez-toni-php--xml--mysql).

Answer (score 1):

когда ты превращаешь xml в объект simplexml, он не наполняется магически  подобъектами с теми же именами. Но и пых при этом не ругается, когда не находит подобъект.

поэтому цикл пустой.

тебе надо итерировать по $simplexml->children() и обрабатывать подходящие узлы

кривоватый пример здесь: http://pastebin.com/d7g9Q5U0
кривоватый потому, что `as $note` там семантически неправильно.  ) надо было сделать $node (узел)  и проверять свойства узла

(возможно еще лучше, но надо потестить - как советует http://php.net/manual/ru/simplexmlelement.children.php
$sxe->children('foo'); //foo заменяем на node
) 
на будущее: делай var_dump переменной, по которой хочешь пройти в цикле

и да, перейди на нормальную IDE - PhpStorm или Netbeans/Eclipse, что-нибудь что будет указывать на очевидные ошибки

и включи отображение ошибок в php

rtfm, короче

Comment: pastebin.com/Hxakrdff А сейчас что не так?

Comment: кстати, твоего xml я не вижу в вопросе, так бы на нем проэкспериментировал

Comment: это xml <goods> <good sh="1235643" name="qwezxc" ed="dsa" cost="98754"/> <good sh="123" name="qwe" ed="oopopop" cost="123456"/> </goods>

Вот xml мой

Что-то все равно не робит((

Comment: http://pastebin.com/unCszwyM

Comment: http://pastebin.com/5jUbygAX

Comment: http://pastebin.com/6c6knq8a
Вот,вот так???

Comment: http://pastebin.com/qZpnay33 ты $goods опять вардампаешь, но на верном пути

Comment: по моей ссылке видно, что в твои переменные $sh, $name и т.д. данные попадают

Comment: http://pastebin.com/24YuiuCq

Тааааааааак?

Comment: ааааааааааааааа?

Comment: верните свой foreach или проверяйте имя ноды. Хотя лучше верните. Если нет заморочек с пространством имен xml, это ненужное усложнение итерратора

Answer (score 0):

1) У вас sh, name, ed, cost - они в БД все типа char/varchar? если нет, то надо убрать лишние апострофы

2) не используйте mysql, используйте mysqli

3) в xml у вас goods, а цикл почему то по $xml->good

Comment: да,все типа varchar

изменил на на goods - не помогло

Comment: * в xml у вас goods, а цикл почему то по $xml->good* - simplxml не видит корневой элемент, только сохраняет его атрибуты, как атрибуты переменной, хранящей  объект